# How exactly does google activity recognition work?

Tags: android-activity, google-api, activity-recognition

On the web, google documentation and other documents I can find only information related to its implementation.

I'd like to know how does it exactly work. For example what sensors is it using, how does the machine learning thing was done, whats the measurement error probability etc.

Are those infos restricted or just hard to find?